# Vue.JS + webpack build issue with event emission

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

Using the eventBus pattern in Vue.js allows a central place to emit events so that subscribing listening components can handle such events.

The below code snippets are setting up listeners on child components to receive an updated Object `server` when a particular UI change happens.

I ran into something today where this DID'T work in a child component:

```
created: function() {
        eventBus.$on('serverSelected', function(server) {
            console.log('serverDetails, server=' + server.toString());
            this.server = server;
    });
},
```

but this DID work:

```
created: function() {
        eventBus.$on('serverSelected', (server) => {
            console.log('serverDetails, server=' + server.toString());
            this.server = server;
    });
},
```

I believe the only different is the ES6 syntax for the callback. But the vanilla JS should still work right?

I'm very new to JS. Why is there a different and why does only the second version work?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major difference between `function(){}` and `() => {}` is precisely how `this` will be handled inside the scope of the function.

With the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`() => {}`), `this` will be handled lexically; meaning it will point to the containing scope.

From the MDN documentation linked above,

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has
>   its original meaning from the enclosing context

With the regular function expression, what `this` refers to depends on how the method is called. In your case it probably refers to `eventBus`.

Again, from the MDN documentation,

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the context object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.).

That's why it works with the arrow function, but not with the regular function, because with the arrow function, `this` points to the Vue that has the `server` property, and with the regular function, it points to the `eventBus`.

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/rmLvEr?editors=1010) showing the difference. Pop open the console to see the different messages.

If you wanted to continue to use the regular function, you would need to bind `this` appropriately. One way is to use `bind`.

```
created: function() {
        eventBus.$on('serverSelected', function(server) {
            console.log('serverDetails, server=' + server.toString());
            this.server = server;
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Or you could use a closure.

```
created: function() {
        const self = this
        eventBus.$on('serverSelected', function(server) {
            console.log('serverDetails, server=' + server.toString());
            self.server = server;
    });
},
```

See also, [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)